# Displaying 12 records per row with bootstrap, the remainder should go to the next row

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a dynamic number of users in the bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="Contact in Contacts" class="col-md-{{12 / Contacts.Count}}">
        <img ng-src="../../Images/{{Contact.ContactImage}}.png" alt="{{Contacts.Name}}" />
        <h4 class="subtitle">{{Contacts.FullName}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above works while there are less than 12 contacts. But if there are more, I want them to go to the next row. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you show an example or in a codepen. I think what you are doing is quite possible however I want to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you must be aware that bootstrap *scales up to 12 columns*.
So, in order to include 12 columns in a row, you need to divide your row in 12 equal sized columns. And [col-md-1](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) does just that. Additionally, you can also use `col-sm-1 col-xs-1` as per your viewport requirement.
Change your code to:
`<div ng-repeat="Contact in Contacts" class="col-md-1">`

You can skip this `class="col-md-{{12 / Contacts.Count}}"`, as you are already aware of you 12-column requirement. In case your `Contacts.Count` is 5, then in that case, 12/5 = *2.4*, and there is no such class as `col-md-2.4` in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid system automatically wraps overflowing columns to the next row by default, so you don't technically need to change your current code at all.  For instance...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">I'm in the first row</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">I'm in the first row</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">I'm in the second row!!!!!!</div>
</div>
```

If you want to actually use a separate `div` row for each set of 12 columns; that's easily doable as well.  Just create two loops like so:

```
var contacts = [{...}, {...}, ...]; // assume this is an array of 20 objects

for (var i = 0, n = Math.ceil(contacts.length/12); i < n; i++) {
    // print <div class="row"> here
    for (var j = i*12; j < Math.min(i*12+12, contacts.length); j++) {
        console.log('row', i, 'col', j);
        // print <div class="col-md-1">contacts[j].RANDOM_DATA</div> here
    }
    // print </div> here
}
```

Here's a super basic/quick fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/67L1h1v5/

Comment: michael, without ng-repreat it only display one item

Comment: Are you using some variant of Bootstrap or an additional library?  Pure Bootstrap doesn't require an `ng-repreat` class.  It sounds like you might be using AngularJS, which I'm not familiar with and wasn't mentioned in the OP.